# List all Assembly related a Blazor WASM application

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

Is there any way to list all DLL related to a Blazor WASM application?
Via `HttpClient`, for example, it is possible to get a specific assembly.

> ```cs
> List<Assembly> assemblies = new();
> Stream stream = await http.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:5010/_framework/SpecificAssembly.dll");
> Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);
> assemblies.Add(assembly);
> ```

My goal, however, is to get them all back.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, as we all know, is not viable because only return loaded assemblies.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: How about [`GetReferencedAssemblies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies)? It is unclear what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

To list all DLLs related to a Blazor WASM application, simply parse the contents of the blazor.boot.json file via HttpClient.

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync($"{path}/_framework/blazor.boot.json");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
BootstrapInfo bootstrap = BootstrapInfo.FromJson(json);
IEnumerable<string> dlls = bootstrap.Resources.Assembly.Select(assembly => assembly.Key);
```

Comment: where is `BootstrapInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

In response to Alex, here is the code for the BootstrapInfo class:

```
public class BootstrapInfo
{
    private static JsonSerializerOptions SerializationOptions => new() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

    [JsonConstructor]
    public BootstrapInfo()
    {
        Resources = new BootstrapResourceInfo();
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("cacheBootResources")]
    public bool CacheBootResources { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("config")]
    public List<string> Config { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("debugBuild")]
    public bool DebugBuild { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("entryAssembly")]
    public string EntryAssembly { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("icuDataMode")]
    public long IcuDataMode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("linkerEnabled")]
    public bool LinkerEnabled { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("resources")]
    public BootstrapResourceInfo Resources { get; set; }

    public static BootstrapInfo FromJson(string json) => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BootstrapInfo>(json, SerializationOptions);

    public static string ToJson(BootstrapInfo bootstrap) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(bootstrap, SerializationOptions);
}
```